# brother mfc 7360n scaner and ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, scanner, brother

so i run ubuntu 14.04 i386 on a new box. and my old printer/scaner that used to work isnt fully working now.
 printer is working fine.

scaner isnt working. even after going over many documentry and Qs around the web.
thing is its connected and driver is installed:

`dpkg -l | grep Brother output`:

```
ii  brother-udev-rule-type1                               1.0.0-1                                             all          Brother udev rule type 1
ii  brscan-skey                                           0.2.4-1                                             i386         Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                               0.4.2-4                                             i386         Brother Scanner Driver
ii  cupswrappermfc7360n                                   2.0.4-2                                             i386         Brother MFC7360N CUPS wrapper driver
ii  mfc7360nlpr                                           2.1.0-1                                             i386         Brother MFC-7360N LPR driver
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                                 1.3-8                                               amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

**lsusb output:**

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f9:0270 Brother Industries, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0461:4d20 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: did you run the xsane?

Comment: When runing xsane it also doesnt recognize the scanner

Comment: Have you tried scanning as root?

Comment: ya...
maybe xsane and the driver cant work together?